# nushell: Add computed column to table

Tags: nushell

How can I add a column in a table in nushell, which computes its values from other columns?

For example, I would like to split the column "name" into "path without name" and "local name" for `ls -a -f **/*`, by adding these two columns and dropping the original "name" column.

The official documentation has a section [Adding a new column](http://www.nushell.sh/book/working_with_tables.html#adding-a-new-column). But it explains how to add a ROW, not a COLUMN. There is even an [GitHub issue](https://github.com/nushell/nushell.github.io/issues/112) for that mixup, but it is still open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`insert` really is, I believe, what you are looking for, despite the confusing example in the book.

Try:

```
ls -af **/* | insert path { $in.name | path dirname } | update name { $in.name | path basename }
```

That inserts a new `path` column and updates (rather than drops) the existing `name` column to just show the name.

You can clean it up a bit and make it easier to call by putting it in a function:

```
def split-ls [] {
    insert path { $in.name | path dirname } | 
    update name { $in.name | path basename }
}
```

Then invoke with:

```
ls -af **/* | split-ls
```

If you really want two new columns and to remove the existing name:

```
ls -af **/* | insert path { $in.name | path dirname } | insert base { $in.name | path basename } | move path --before name | move base --before path | reject name
```

Or, as above:

```
def split-ls [ --help (-h) ] { 
    insert path { $in.name | path dirname } |
    insert base { $in.name | path basename } |
    move path --before name |
    move base --before path |
    reject name
}

ls -af **/* | split-ls
```

Comment: If you want to use external commands here, make sure you convert their output to nushell types: `... | insert thing { wl-paste -t $in.type | into string }`